# If statement condition in powershell time range

Tags: powershell

I have the following code where I am trying to find the value in respect to particualr time of a day.  I am using the following for loop with if statement.

I have tried but confused about the if (condition?) logic

```
$currentTime = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
$poolProfileWorkdayArray: [
          {
            "time": "00:02",
            "hotAmount": 1,
            "coldAmount": 1
          },
          {
            "time": "05:00",
            "hotAmount": 2,
            "coldAmount": 2
          },
          {
            "time": "09:00",
            "hotAmount": 3,
            "coldAmount": 3
          },
          {
            "time": "14:21",
            "hotAmount": 4,
            "coldAmount": 4
          }
        ]


--------------------------------------------------

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $($poolProfileWorkdayArray.count); $i++) { 

       Write-Output "test for $i : $($poolProfileWorkdayArray[$i])"

     if (($currentTime -ge $poolProfileWorkdayArray[$i - 1]) -and ($currentTime -le $poolProfileWorkdayArray[$i])) {

       Write-Output $poolProfileWorkdayArray[$i - 1]
       $customImageColdVmAmount = $poolProfileWorkdayArray[$i - 1].coldAmount

Write-Output "Cold amount for custom weekDay is : $poolProfileWorkdayArray[$i-1].coldAmount)"

                            break
                        }
                    }
```

What I am looking for is that it will go thorugh the loop and chek that is the current time betwwen the array values and the give the $customImageColdVmAmount value. I tried it and found the when the current time is 17.30, it doesn't work and not values from $customImageColdVmAmount. What is the right if condition here?

Comment: @Arafatful Welcome to Stackoverflow. The issue you have with this approach is JSON does not guarantee order, and you are retrieving each property by numbered index.

Answer (score 0):

I made some corrections to your code. Yet, I may not be clear on your expected output use case, but do you mean this.

```
($currentTime = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm")

# Results

<#
17:39
#>

 $poolProfileWorkdayArray = @'
[
    {
        "time": "00:02",
        "hotAmount": 1,
        "coldAmount": 1
    },
    {
        "time": "05:00",
        "hotAmount": 2,
        "coldAmount": 2
    },
    {
        "time": "09:00",
        "hotAmount": 3,
        "coldAmount": 3
    },
    {
        "time": "18:21",
        "hotAmount": 4,
        "coldAmount": 4
    }
]
'@

($WorkDayArray = $poolProfileWorkdayArray | ConvertFrom-Json)

# Results
<#
time  hotAmount coldAmount
----  --------- ----------
00:02         1          1
05:00         2          2
09:00         3          3
18:21         4          4
#>



 for ($i = 0; $i -lt $($WorkDayArray.count); $i++) 
{ 
    "test for $i : $($WorkDayArray.time[$i])"

    if (($currentTime -ge $WorkDayArray.time[$i - 1]) -and ($currentTime -le $WorkDayArray.time[$i])) 
    {
        $WorkDayArray[$i - 1]
        $customImageColdVmAmount = $WorkDayArray[$i - 1].coldAmount

        "Cold amount for custom weekDay is : $($WorkDayArray[$i-1].coldAmount)"

        break
    }
}

# Results
<#
test for 0 : 00:02
test for 1 : 05:00
test for 2 : 09:00
test for 3 : 18:21

time  hotAmount coldAmount
----  --------- ----------
09:00         3          3
Cold amount for custom weekDay is : 3
#>
```

Comment: If the time is between 18:21 and 00:02, how can get the  cold amount value 4? In the present if condition it doesn't return anything when current time is e.g. 19.00 How can I make this logic working for all different times? @postanote